# JSP - How to submit form when clicking a link?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

I want to submit a form when I click on a link but when I click the element it doesn't prevent the default action. And I also get this message error: `HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported`. This is what I tried so far:

users.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/template/taglibs.jsp"%>    
<div class="container">
    <%@ include file="menu.jsp" %>
    <a class="btn btn-warning addbtn buttons" href="http://localhost:8080/Catering/index/addUser">Add</a>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden">Id</td>
                    <td>First name</td>
                    <td>Last name</td>
                    <td>User name</td>
                    <td class="table-row-option"></td>
                    <td class="table-row-option"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="hidden">${item.getUserid()}</td>
                        <td>${item.getFname()}</td>
                        <td>${item.getLname()}</td>
                        <td>${item.getUsername()}</td>
                        <td class="table-row-option">                               
                            <a class="btn btn-warning buttons col-width" href="http://localhost:8080/Catering/index/editUser?id=${item.getUserid()}">Edit</a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="table-row-option">
                            <form:form method="post" action="#" commandName="delete">
                                <input type="hidden" value="${item.getUserid()}" name="id"/>
                                <a class="btn btn-warning buttons col-width lnk-delete" href="#">Delete</a>                             
                            </form:form>                    
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>        
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("a.lnk-delete").click(function(event){
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var frm = $(this).closest('form');
            frm.submit();
        }); 

    });
</script>
```

UsersController.java

```
package catering.web.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import catering.web.data_access.UserDataAccess;
import catering.web.data_access.UserSummaryDataAccess;
import catering.web.mapper.UserMapper;
import catering.web.model.UserModel;
import catering.web.model.UserModelSummary;
import catering.web.view_model.UserViewModel;


@Controller
public class UsersController {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("controller");
    static final String guid = "1390e9e7-7792-4e24-b66f-6da90b8ebefb";

    @RequestMapping(value = "users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String indexUsers(Model model, Authentication authentication){

        logger.debug("Received request to users page(GET)");

        List<UserModelSummary> users = UserSummaryDataAccess.getUsersSummary();

        model.addAttribute("username", "You are logged in as " + authentication.getPrincipal());
        model.addAttribute("list", users);

        return "users";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addUserPage(Model model,Authentication authentication){

        logger.debug("Received request to show add user page(GET)");    

        populateDrop(model);
        model.addAttribute("username", "You are logged in as " + authentication.getPrincipal());
        model.addAttribute("addForm", new UserViewModel());


        return "adduser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("addForm") UserViewModel model, Model viewmodel){

        logger.debug("Received request to show add user page(POST)");   

        int isValid = 0;



        if(model.getConfirmedpassword().equals(model.getPass())){

            //map the view model to database model
            UserModel user = UserMapper.mapUVMtoUM(model);          

            isValid = UserDataAccess.insertUser(user);
            if(isValid != -1){
                return "redirect:users";
            } else {
                viewmodel.addAttribute("error", "The username already exists!");
                return "adduser";
            }

        } else{         
            viewmodel.addAttribute("passeorr", "Password unmatch!");
            return "adduser";
        }       
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEditUserPage(@RequestParam int id, Model model, Authentication authentication) {



        logger.debug("Received request to show edit user page(GET)");   

        model.addAttribute("username", "You are logged in as " + authentication.getPrincipal());
        populateDrop(model);

        UserModel user = UserDataAccess.getUserById(id);

        UserViewModel userVM = UserMapper.mapUMtoUVM(user);
        userVM.setPass(guid);
        userVM.setConfirmedpassword(guid);  
        model.addAttribute("id", userVM.getId());
        model.addAttribute("firstName", userVM.getFirstName());
        model.addAttribute("lastName", userVM.getLastName());
        model.addAttribute("role", userVM.getRole());
        model.addAttribute("user_name", userVM.getUser_name());
        model.addAttribute("pass", userVM.getPass());




        model.addAttribute("editForm", userVM);

        return "edituser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editUser(@ModelAttribute("editForm") UserViewModel model, Model viewmodel){

        logger.debug("Received request to show edit user page(POST)");  

        if(model.getRole().equals("NONE")){
            viewmodel.addAttribute("error", "You need to select a role!");
            return "edituser";
        }       

        if(model.getPass().equals(model.getConfirmedpassword()) && model.getPass().equals(guid)){

            UserModel user = UserMapper.mapUVMtoUM(model);
            int inserted = UserDataAccess.updateWithoutPassword(user);  
            if(inserted != -1){
                return "redirect:users";
            } else{
                viewmodel.addAttribute("error", "The username already exists!");
                return "edituser";
            }
        } else {
            UserModel user = UserMapper.mapUVMtoUM(model);
            int inserted = UserDataAccess.updateWithPassword(user);
            if(inserted != -1){
                return "redirect:users";
            } else{
                viewmodel.addAttribute("error", "The username already exists!");
                return "edituser";
            }
        }       

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "#", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteUser(@ModelAttribute("delete") @RequestParam int id){

        logger.debug("Received request to delete user page(POST)");


        UserDataAccess.deleteUser(id);
        return "redirect:users";
    }   


    private void populateDrop(Model model){
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
        roles.add("ADMIN");
        roles.add("USER");
        model.addAttribute("roles",roles);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you supply the entire UsersController so we can see the annotations on the controller itself?

Comment: @david99world I added the entire code of UsersController.

Comment: do you think whether `#` is a valid for the request mapping ?

Comment: @sankrish you were right. `#` it isn't valid for the request mapping. I modified the code and iti works. Can you supply an answer to can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below ,

```
<form:form method="post" action="#" commandName="delete">
     <input type="hidden" value="${item.getUserid()}" name="id"/>
     <a class="btn btn-warning buttons col-width lnk-delete" href="#">Delete</a>                             
</form:form>
```

`action="#"` is not a valid url to map the request . as it load the same

so try to map it with a new name in the controller

Hope this helps !!